# Circular dependency when squashing Django migrations

Tags: python, django

We've created a large Django application, and we want to squash migrations. However, the squashed migrations have circular dependencies between the apps in our application. How can we break those circular dependencies without breaking Django's migration squashing?

I've created a [small sample project](https://github.com/donkirkby/djsquash/tree/before_squash) to reproduce the problem. The project has two apps: `fruit` and `meat`. An `Apple` has many `Bacon`
children, and a `Bacon` has many `Cranberry` children. You can see that the fruit app depends on the meat app, and the meat app depends on the fruit app.

The first commit creates all three models with a name field on each and
foreign keys from `Cranberry` to `Bacon` and from `Bacon` to `Apple`. Calling `makemigrations` creates three migrations:

- `fruit/0001_initial` creates the `Apple` and `Cranberry` models
- `meat/0001_initial` creates the `Bacon` model with its foreign key to `Apple`
- `fruit/0002_cranberry_bacon` adds the foreign key from `Cranberry` to `Bacon`

The next commit adds an `Apple.size` field just so there is something to squash.
Calling `makemigrations` adds another migration:

- `fruit/0003_apple_size` adds the `size` field

Running `squashmigrations` now creates a squashed migration with a circular dependency. The [`squashmigrations` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) gives this advice:

> To manually resolve a `CircularDependencyError`, break out one of the ForeignKeys in the circular dependency loop into a separate migration, and move the dependency on the other app with it. If you’re unsure, see how makemigrations deals with the problem when asked to create brand new migrations from your models. In a future release of Django, squashmigrations will be updated to attempt to resolve these errors itself.

If I do that, however, the extra migration isn't configured properly as a replacement. That means that my current database that has gone through the original migrations tries to add the foreign key field again and fails.

```
$ ./manage.py migrate
...
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "bacon_id" of relation "fruit_cranberry" already exists
```

How can I tell the migration system that two new migrations replace all the old migrations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Django versions after 1.9, it seems harder to avoid the `CircularDependencyError`. When Django loads the graph of migrations and applies the replacements, it includes all the dependencies of the replaced migrations as dependencies of the new migration. That means that even when you split the dependency on another app out of the main squashed migration, you still get the dependency from one of the old migrations you replaced.

This seems like a horrible mess to disentangle, but if you absolutely must find a way to squash your migrations, here's what I got to work on my small [sample project](https://github.com/donkirkby/djsquash):

1. Remove all of the migrations.

   ```
   $ rm fruit/migrations/0*
   $ rm meat/migrations/0*
   ```
2. Create a new set of migrations. This is the only way that I've seen Django properly break dependency cycles by separating `0001_initial` and `0002_cranberry_bacon`.

   ```
   $ ./manage.py makemigrations 
   Migrations for 'fruit':
     fruit/migrations/0001_initial.py
       - Create model Apple
       - Create model Cranberry
     fruit/migrations/0002_cranberry_bacon.py
       - Add field bacon to cranberry
   Migrations for 'meat':
     meat/migrations/0001_initial.py
       - Create model Bacon
   ```
3. Rename the new migrations to be replacements, and restore the old migrations.

   ```
   $ mv fruit/migrations/0001_initial.py fruit/migrations/0101_squashed.py
   $ mv fruit/migrations/0002_cranberry_bacon.py fruit/migrations/0102_link_apps.py
   $ git checkout -- .
   ```
4. Change the new migrations to actually be replacements for the old migrations. Look through the old migrations to see which ones depend on the other app. List those migrations in `0102_link_apps.py`, and list all the other migrations in `0101_squashed.py`.

   ```
   # Added to 0101_squashed.py
   replaces = [(b'fruit', '0001_initial'), (b'fruit', '0003_apple_size')]

   # Added to 0102_link_apps.py
   replaces = [(b'fruit', '0002_cranberry_bacon')]
   ```
5. Now comes the painful part on a large project. All of the old migrations that depend on the other app have to be taken out of the dependency chain. In my example, `0003_apple_size` now depends on `0001_initial` instead of `0002_cranberry_bacon`. Of course, Django gets upset if you have more than one leaf node in an app's migrations, so you need to link the two dependency chains back together at the end. Here's `fruit/migrations/0100_prepare_squash.py`:

   ```
   from __future__ import unicode_literals

   from django.db import migrations


   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       dependencies = [
           ('fruit', '0003_apple_size'),
           ('fruit', '0002_cranberry_bacon'),
       ]

       operations = [
       ]
   ```
6. Add `0100_prepare_squash` to the list of migrations that `0102_link_apps` replaces.

   ```
   # Added to 0102_link_apps.py
   replaces = [(b'fruit', '0002_cranberry_bacon'), (b'fruit', '0100_prepare_squash')]
   ```

This seems horribly dangerous, particularly making changes to the dependencies of the old migrations. I guess you could make the dependency chain more elaborate to ensure that everything runs in the correct order, but that would be even more painful to set up.

Comment: I'm not going to use this solution, but the explanation in it is very valuable, so +1.

Comment: Incredibly helpful to know that replaced migrations are still included in the dependency graph! Took me hours to find out!

Answer (score 13):

This seems like a lot of work, but it's the best solution I've found so far. I've posted the squashed migrations in the [master branch](https://github.com/donkirkby/djsquash/tree/master). Before running `squashmigrations`, we replace the foreign key
from `Cranberry` to `Bacon` with an integer field. Override the field name so it
has the `_id` suffix of a foreign key. This will break the dependency without losing data.

```
# TODO: switch back to the foreign key.
# bacon = models.ForeignKey('meat.Bacon', null=True)
bacon = models.IntegerField(db_column='bacon_id', null=True)
```

Run `makemigrations` and rename the migration to show that it is starting
the squash process:

- `fruit/0100_unlink_apps` converts the foreign key to an integer field

Now run `squashmigrations fruit 0100` and rename the migration to make it easier
to follow the sequence:

- `fruit/0101_squashed` combines all the migrations from 1 to 100.

Comment out the dependency from `fruit/0101_squashed` to `meat/0001_initial`. It
isn't really needed, and it creates a circular dependency. With more complicated
migration histories, the foreign keys to other apps might not get optimized out.
Search the file for all the app names listed in the dependencies to see if there
are any foreign keys left. If so, manually replace them with the integer fields.
Usually, this means replacing a `CreateModel(...ForeignKey...)` and
`AlterModel(...IntegerField...)` with a `CreateModel(...IntegerField...)`.

The next commit contains all these changes for demonstration purposes. It
wouldn't make sense to push it without the following commit, though, because
the apps are still unlinked.

Switch back to the foreign key from `Cranberry` to `Bacon`, and run
`makemigrations` one last time. Rename the migration to show that it is
finishing the squash process:

- `fruit/0102_relink_apps` converts the integer field back to a foreign key

Remove the dependency from `fruit/0102_relink_apps` to `fruit/0101_squashed`,
and add a dependency from `fruit/0102_relink_apps` to `fruit/0100_unlink_apps`.
The original dependency just won't work. Take the dependencies that were
commented out in `fruit/0101_squashed` and add them to `fruit/0102_relink_apps`.
That will ensure the links get created in the right order.

Run the test suite to show that the squashed migration works properly. If you
can, test against something other than SQLite, because it doesn't catch some
foreign key problems. Back up the development or production database and run
`migrate` to see that the unlinking and relinking of the apps doesn't break
anything.

Take a nap.

### Bonus section: after all installations are squashed

The [convert_squash branch](https://github.com/donkirkby/djsquash/tree/convert_squash) shows what could happen in the future once all
installations have migrated past the squash point. Delete all the migrations
from 1 to 100, because they've been replaced by 101. Delete the `replaces` list
from `fruit/0101_squashed`. Run `showmigrations` to check for any broken
dependencies, and replace them with `fruit/0101_squashed`.

### The horror of many-to-many relationships

If you are unlucky enough to have a many-to-many relationship between two apps, it gets really ugly. I had to use [the `SeparateDatabaseAndState` operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#separatedatabaseandstate) to disconnect the two apps without having to write a data migration. The trick is to replace the many-to-many relationship with a temporary child model using the same table and field names, then tell Django to just update its state without touching the database schema. To see an example, look at my [unlink](https://github.com/cfe-lab/Kive/blob/2d411bdcc99678b8c39666e6383998743c19254c/kive/pipeline/migrations/0100_unlink_apps.py#L16), [squashed](https://github.com/cfe-lab/Kive/blob/2d411bdcc99678b8c39666e6383998743c19254c/kive/pipeline/migrations/0101_squashed2.py#L162), and [relink](https://github.com/cfe-lab/Kive/blob/2d411bdcc99678b8c39666e6383998743c19254c/kive/pipeline/migrations/0102_relink_apps.py#L17) migrations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [django-replace-migration](https://github.com/3YOURMIND/django-replace-migrations), which I have written to make it easier to remove old migrations.